# Showing that a sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $u_{\phi (n)}-u_n \to 0$ for every extraction $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ (increasing function)
Show that $u$ is convergent.

What I've done : Since we have no idea of the limit I want to use the Cauchy Criterion, so we set $\varepsilon >0$ and we are looking for $N \ge 0$ such that : $$ |u_{n+p}-u_n| \le \varepsilon $$ for every $n \ge N$.

Why should I do then ?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply take $\phi(n)=n+p$ and conclude.

Comment: +Crostul, be careful the bound has to be uniform in $p$, i.e., $$|u_{n+p}-u_n|\leq\epsilon\quad\forall n\geq N,p\geq1.$$  Your suggestion does not obviously lead to this.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $|u_{n+p} - u_n| \to 0$ doesn't imply that the sequence converges. The Cauchy criterion demands much more than that.

Turn the problem around: if $\{u_n\}$ is divergent, then it fails the Cauchy criterion. Thus there is $\epsilon > 0$ with the property that for any $N$ you can find $n > m \ge N$ with the property that $|u_n - u_m| > \epsilon$. Use this to work on a constructing an extraction $\phi$ with the property that $|u_{\phi(n)} - u_n| > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.